# Using X-CTU to setup XBee modem

Tags: xbee, arduino, zigbee

I recently got an XBee Pro Series 2.5 and another XBee Series 2.5 as listed here:

- http://www.littlebirdelectronics.com/products/XBee-2mW-Series-2.5-Chip-Antenna.html
- http://www.littlebirdelectronics.com/products/XBee-Pro-50mW-Series-2.5-U.FL-Connection.html

I then downloaded the latest version of X-CTU so that I could attempt to configure the XBees for use as a serial communication between two Arduinos.

When I launch X-CTU, the 'com test' works fine, and I see my modems with firmware version 1247 for both, and types 'XB24-B' and 'XBP24-B' for the normal and 'pro' XBees respectively.

However, here's the problem: when I click the 'Modem Configuration' tab, and then click 'Read', I am repeatedly told that "The modem configuration file was not found. Would you like to check the website for updates? (Recommended)" and then, on clicking 'Yes', "Modem configuration file not found after update".

The Digi people have weirdly fobbed me off with some comment about my hardware no longer being supported... but it's brand new stuff as far as I can tell. The Pro XBee says "Model:XBEEPRO2" and the regular XBee says "IC:4214-XBEE2".

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: reinstall the application is the best suggestion I have.

Comment: reinstalling was no help in this case.

Comment: Yeah, i see the first answer. I have had a problem like this before and reinstalling helped alot.

Answer (score 3):

I made some progress on this after chatting live with Eric from Digi support, and also reading around HOWTOs on the net.

First point is that the XBee 2.5 model is discontinued and no longer supported by Digi, even though it's still pretty widely sold. Eric mentioned that there are some better and more up-to-date models available, I think the 'ZB' line rather than the 'ZNet' is what you want. But I'm not completely clear on that yet (and I have the 2.5 which I wanted to get working).

Next, because the XBee 2.5 and XBee PRO 2.5 are no longer supported, the firmware is not available automatically from the X-CTU program. To get the firmware, you can still download it manually, and then use the 'File' option in the X-CTU download tool to get X-CTU to use the latest firmware. The firmware I needed was on this page: http://www.digi.com/support/productdetl.jsp?pid=3261&osvid=0&s=269&tp=2&tp2=0

Next, you can follow the information in the 'Xbee Configuration guide', see link at http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoXbeeShield

You have to set up one XBee as 'ZNET 2.5 COMMUNICATOR AT' (the 'home base' xbee) and the other as 'ZNET 2.5 ROUTER/ENDPOINT AT' (the 'remote' xbee). You can assign names (ID) and network IDs (PAN ID) to both XBees using X-CTU.

Using this approach, the serial test worked OK, so it's looking good. According to Eric, what one should really be doing here is upgrading the firmware to the new 'ZB' feature set, for which instructions are here:

http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/upgradingfromznettozb.pdf

I'm entirely sure why one should do that, other than to enable digi to support you better, because they don't actually support the ZNet modules, which apparently date from year 2006.

Comment: Another comment from Eric was that the 2.5 series is not necessarily the most modern and up-to-date in the XBee family. Any one with more detail on this please let me know.